# How to distinguish 'Role' interfaces from 'Result' interfaces?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

This issue comes up for me so often in my coding that I'm astonished I can find so little reference to it, and would value other people's thoughts and ideas.

I define lots of APIs, for the frameworks I work on, and within large domain models that I want to break up. Those APIs consist almost entirely of interfaces (meaning, in my case, C# interfaces). I find, over and over again, that I want to distinguish between two kinds of interface. In the absence of finding any more widely used terms, I define these two as follows:

- 'Role' interfaces are intended to be implemented by objects outside of the API, in order that those objects can be used as arguments for methods defined on the API.
- 'Result' interfaces are implemented by objects inside the API and made available to other parts of the system via the API. The intent of defining a result interface rather than exposing the object that implements it is to restrict the view of the object to the outside world.

To pick one example, a Payments sub-system might define IPayableItem as a Role interface, implemented by many types in other parts of the application in order that Payments may be generated for them.  Those generated Payment objects may be retrieved via the API but defined by the Result interface IPayment.

The only way I can currently distinguish these is by naming convention and/or commenting.  Ideally, I would like the distinction enforced by the language, and have it enforce the rule:  you can't implement a Result interface outside the API, only use it. But C# doesn't provide any such mechanism.  (Can anyone advise me of a language that does?). I could define an attribute, but this still wouldn't enforce anything.

Another important significance of the distinction lies in Semantic Versioning of the API.  If I add a new member to a Role interface then this should be seen as a breaking change (and hence a first-level version) -  because any existing external implementations will need to add that member.  But if I add a member to what I deem to be a 'Result' interface then it should only be my own code that is impacted  -  it is just a new feature (second-level version) for everyone else. But with no enforced distinction between the two types there's some risk that people are implementing the Result interfaces and hence their code would be broken.

Has anyone else encountered this dilemma? If so, how have you dealt with it? I look forward to your answers.

But please don't both to respond with either of the following arguments (which I have heard all too often):

- My Result interfaces should be abstract classes rather than interfaces.  This does not solve the problem, and potentially makes it worse, since external code can sub-class them.
- I should be returning the concrete type and ensuring that anything I don't want accessible outside the API is marked 'internal'. There are lots of cases where I need things inside the API to be public, e.g. to be accessible to other frameworks (not going through the API).

Comment: `you can't implement a Result interface outside the API, only use it.` So presumably your API only ever returns a `Result` interface and doesn't have any methods that accept a `Result` as an argument. If that's the case, what does it matter if a client implements a class with a `Result` interface? They can't do anything with it (at least as far as your API is concerned) anyway. Anything they do with it is completely on them. If they are trying to wrap your API and add some extra functionality (by implementing their own `Result`), why should you stop them anyway?

Comment: *There are lots of cases where I need things inside the API to be public, e.g. to be accessible to other frameworks (not going through the API).* - do you mean third-party frameworks? Third-party frameworks built on your APIs are just like any other consumers, which means these interfaces are semantically public and your conventions, documentation and versioning should reflect this. If you *don't* mean third-party APIs then they can be internal and exposed to other internal assemblies via `InternalsVisibleTo`.

Comment: @Matt  Even if my result interface is never used as a param input on the API, it still matters -  and I gave one of the reasons in my original posting -  see my comments on SemVer. But it is also perfectly legimate for one of those result interfaces to be used as an input param  -  and then I want to be sure that it is an object that was created inside the API.

Comment: @Ant P.  The third party frameworks don't work through my API, and can't.  They typically provide lower level capabilities. To pick one real and simple example: a persistence mechanism such as Entity Framework.

Comment: But they *do* work through your API. Otherwise you wouldn't "need things inside the API to be public." The fact is, if it needs to be public, it is part of your external API and should be treated as such. If not, it can be made internal. There isn't really any grey area. It's then up to your consumers to consume the appropriate parts of your public API for what they want to do and up to you to deal with issues of appropriate versioning and compatibility.

Comment: If all you're trying to do is stop people from implementing certain interfaces themselves, then I can see no good case for doing that. In the example of SemVer, if you make a breaking change to a public interface, it is a breaking change regardless of whether people are implementing it or just consuming it

Comment: @Ant P. "But they do work through your API".  No.  Product X works through my API if it depends on me, not vice versa.  To pick a simple example, my implementation of my API depends on Entity Framework; Entity Framework does not depend  -  in any sense  - on my API.

Comment: @Ant P.  Adding a member to an existing interface is only a breaking change to anyone (external) that is implementing that interface. (Changing the signature of an existing member does, obviously).  To pick another example, an API will often expose a service interface, and adding another method to a service interface does not typically impact an external consumer  -  unless they (for no obvious reason) decide to re-implement that service externally.  The same should go for a result.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet? I agree with @MattBurland's comment about it not mattering if the interface is implemented or not. If a Result interface were to become a parameter to an API method, you could add a type of CheckSum or HashCode property, which is an aggregation of all the other properties in the interface. Then when the interface is received as an input parameter, you could validate the checksum of the properties ensuring that no one's tampered with it. More of a workaround than a solution though :|

Comment: "Have you found a solution for this yet?  "  I have not found a solution in terms of how to enforce it  -  but I have been implementing the distinction for years.  Most of my result interfaces have an Id property, I could check that the object being passed in .Equals the object I can retrieve inside the API for that Id.  I don't usually bother.  I was more interested in finding a more elegant technical solution that would provide more intentionality to the developer outside the API  -  preventing, or at least warning, them that a Result interface was not intended to be implemented.

Comment: I see you have already considered abstract classes, but your requirement "you can't implement a Result interface outside the API" can be fulfilled by using a abstract class with only internal constructors. Have you have already found other issues with this approach?

Comment: @David Manning.  That is an intriguing idea, which I've never thought of.  So you're saying:  make the Result type a public abstract type, that has only internal constructors, including the default constructor. This would mean (I assume  -  I haven't ever tried this) that even if some external code were to sub-class it, without access to the default constructor they couldn't instantiate their sub-class.  Is that right?  If that works it is a good answer  -  but I'd like to try it first.

Comment: @RichardPawson, yes that is how it works, done a quick test and you get a compile time error saying no constructors are available if you try to sub class it (no intelli-sense warning though). I haven't used this pattern myself though.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking is it possible to expose an interface, but determine that a given instance is one you created?

If so, you could also create an internal private interface, and mark all your implementations as also implementing the private interface.  Then upon being given an object from the outside world, verify it has the internal interface implementation as well.

```
public interface IPublic
{
    ...
}

internal interface ISecret { }

public class PublicImplementation : IPublic, ISecret
{
    ...
}
```

Only you can implement the ISecret, so even if someone implements the IPublic and passes it to you, it will fail the ISecret test.

Comment: Yes, that does solve one of the issues.  I would prefer a more intentional mechanism that prevented, or warned, developer at compile time.

Comment: More generally, I have been seeking to eliminate cases where my Result interfaces are also used as input parameters on the API.  Where this can't be eliminated I seek to move the whole method onto the Result interface, less one parameter. Nonetheless, I remain surprised that there isn't a more elegant and intentional way to define the two archetypes of interface.